# TypeScript: how to extract the generic parameter from a type?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like `React.ComponentClass<Props>` and I want to reference the `Props` part but it is unnamed in my current context.

To illustrate:

```
const x = makeComponent(); // typeof x = React.ComponentClass<Something>
```

In this situation, I can use `typeof x` but that doesn't give me direct
access to the `Something` type.

What I want is something like this:

```
type GetPropsType<C extends React.ComponentClass<P>> = P
```

So that I can extract `Something` with the type `GetPropsType<typeof x>`

Anything equivalent would be great.

Comment: Why would you do that? What would you use the type for? You cant assign anything without knowing the type, ie: `const y : GetPropsType<typeof x> = ???`

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'd say the only way to do it at runtime is to get an actual object of that type first, and then run typeof on it. In this case, get the props of your react component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript React: Access component property types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230765/typescript-react-access-component-property-types)

Comment: hey have you found some perfect solution? I need to do the same in Vue.js

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use infer:

```
type TypeWithGeneric<T> = T[]
type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends TypeWithGeneric<infer X> ? X : never

type extracted = extractGeneric<TypeWithGeneric<number>>
// extracted === number
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypeWithGeneric%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%5B%5D%0D%0Atype%20extractGeneric%3CType%3E%20%3D%20Type%20extends%20Array%3Cinfer%20X%3E%20%3F%20X%20%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Atype%20extracted%20%3D%20extractGeneric%3CTypeWithGeneric%3Cnumber%3E%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20extracted%20%3D%3D%3D%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: is there a 'generic' version of this where you don't need to know the actual generic class? or is that impossible? I want to extract the generic type 'generically' ;-)

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now @Simon_Weaver, there is no way to generically reference a type construct currently, as Typescript does not support Higher Kindred Types.

Comment: Would prever `never` over `null`.

Comment: How would one get the nth generic parameter?

Comment: related typescript issue: [Allow classes to be parametric in other parametric classes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd share a real world example to extract the `R` generic type for `MatDialogRef<T, R = any>` which is Angular material's dialog box.

I often have components like this, where the output 'model' is a simple interface that isn't quite worthy of its own named type.

```
export class DialogPleaseWaitComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogPleaseWaitModel,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogPleaseWaitModel, { timedOut: boolean }>) { 

  }
```

So I came up with:

```
extractMatDialogResponse<T>
```

I made it work in two 'modes', either taking the component type or the MatDialogRef itself. So I can put `extractMatDialogResponse<DialogPleaseWaitComponent>` and get back `{ timedOut: boolean }` :-)

Yes - if `T` is the component type then it requires `dialogRef` to be the exact name of the property, and it does need to be public.

```
type extractMatDialogResponse<T = MatDialogRef<any, any> | { dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any, any> }> = 
     T extends MatDialogRef<any, infer R> ? R :                                                                                                          
     T extends { dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any, infer R> } ? R : never;
```

Also yes this is the same mechanism as used by Xiv, but demonstrates how to make a 'targeted' extractor for a specific use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my utility types which can be helpful:

```
// ExtractPromise(Result)Type
export type PromiseType<TPromise> = TPromise extends Promise<infer TResult> ? TResult : never;

export type AsyncFunc<T = void, TArg1 = any, TArg2 = any, TArg3 = any> = (arg1?: TArg1, arg2?: TArg2, arg3?: TArg3) => Promise<T>;

export type Func<T = void, TArg1 = any, TArg2 = any, TArg3 = any> = (arg1?: TArg1, arg2?: TArg2, arg3?: TArg3) => T;

// ExtractAsyncResultType
export type AsyncResultType<TFunc> = TFunc extends AsyncFunc<infer TResult> ? TResult : never;

// ExtractArgType
export type ArgType<TFunc, TArgIndex extends number> = TFunc extends Func<infer TResult, infer TArg1, infer TArg2, infer TArg3> ? 
    TArgIndex extends 1? TArg1: TArgIndex extends 2? TArg2: TArgIndex extends 3? TArg3: never : never;
```

Examples:

```
    // basic example
    let promiseType: PromiseType<Promise<number[]>>;
    // promiseType - number[]
    
    async function TestAsync(): Promise<string> {
        return "";
    }
    let resultType: AsyncResultType<typeof TestAsync>;
    // resultType - string
    
    async function Test2Async(arg1: number, arg2: boolean): Promise<string> {
        return "";
    }
    let arg2Type: ArgType<typeof Test2Async, 2>;
    // arg2Type - boolean

    // advanced example
    
    export type ParsedBody = {
        [K in keyof Body as Body[K] extends AsyncFunc<any> ? K : never]?: AsyncResultType<Body[K]>
    };
    let b: ParsedBody;
    // b.blob - Blob
```