# Extract type T from SomeType<T>

Tags: typescript

I was using `ReturnType<typeof function-name>` to extract the return type - very useful.

It now happens that the return type of the function is a Promise, and I want to further extract the type parameter, example:

```js
const someFunction = (): Promise<MysteryType> => { ... some code ... }

type TheReturnType = ReturnType<typeof someFunction>

type ExtractTypeFromPromise = UNKNOWN<TheReturnType>
```

Is this currently possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: how to extract the generic parameter from a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851268/typescript-how-to-extract-the-generic-parameter-from-a-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypeScript docs have a section called ["Type inference in conditional types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) that gives a nice answer with the `Unpacked<T>` type definition:

```
type Unpacked<T> =
    T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
    T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
    T;
```

Along with some examples of the results:

```
type T0 = Unpacked<string>;  // string
type T1 = Unpacked<string[]>;  // string
type T3 = Unpacked<Promise<string>>;  // string
```

I wasn't familiar with inferred types, so thanks for helping me learn something new! :)

---

Update addressing additional question:

> Is there a way to do this where you force the type at compile time to be of that instance.
>   Example: `type T0 = UnpackedArray<string> // fail because it's not an Array`

Yes! It's possible to place constraints on the generic type using `extends`:

```
type UnpackedArray<T extends Array<any>> =
    T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

type T2 = UnpackedArray<string[]>; // string
type T3 = UnpackedArray<string>;   // Error: Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.
```

Comment: Follow up question, is there a way to do this where you force the type at compile time to be of that instance. Example:

`type T0 = UnpackedArray<string> // fail because it's not an Array`

Comment: @ArieMilner Yes, see my updated answer on how to constrain the type at compile time :)