# Infer the generic type parameter of any generic class

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

We have `GetInnerType` type which return the generic type parameter for every type extending `Foo` class:

```js
class Foo<T> {}

type GetInnerType<X> = X extends Foo<infer I> ? I : never;
```

Can we abstract `GetInnerType` so that it works with any generic class?

The new version of `GetInnerType` should behave like below:

```js
class Bar<T>{}

let v1 = new Foo<number>();
let v2 = new Bar<{a: string}>();
type t1 = GetInnerType<typeof v1>; // is number
type t2 = GetInnerType<typeof v2>; // is {a: string}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851268/typescript-how-to-extract-the-generic-parameter-from-a-type

Comment: Thanks. The question you linked is relevant but doesn't answer my question. How to do it for ANY type without having to create more types ?

Comment: You don't. I have linked that question because there is a commenter asking for the same thing, conclusion was that it's currently impossible.

Comment: This is feature is known as higher kinded types. It is not available in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible because the result is not well-defined. Consider the example below:

```
class A<T> {
    constructor(public a: T, public b: number) {}
}

class B<T> {
    constructor(public a: string, public b: T) {}
}

// true
type AextendsB = A<string> extends B<number> ? true : false

// true
type BextendsA = B<number> extends A<string> ? true : false
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gWAFDV9YA9gHYQAuATgK7CkHkAUADpQEYgCWw0YAXNIgBpozNp2gs+RSgFsWAU3IBKdAF9sarNlCQYAISSpMOPIRIVqtBiI5de0MuXZEA5kOtiJ-ZWg0bsAen9oczlsUgBPRjk4OQAPUjkiABMIXWgAXjh4BydnVDiE5L14KVkFVAB+YKpovgAzMBAIUM0sQOrKFoio6F0CxJTYDN6SmXlyfPiBmAQcl0qO2ugGppagA)

Typescript's type system is [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), so if two types have the same structure then they are the same type, even if they were declared with different names. In the above example, the type `A<string>` is equal to the type `B<number>`, and both are equal to `{a: string, b: number}`.

It follows that however you define `GetInnerType`, the result of `GetInnerType<A<string>>` is necessarily the same as the result of `GetInnerType<B<number>>`, so you can't get `string` in the first case and also get `number` in the second case.