# extracting the generic type of other props in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-query

How can I achieve something like this?

```js
interface Props {
   result: <type of function with a lot of generic>
   data: <type of one of the generics in the function above>
}
```

I've found a question that sounds similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924506/1330926), but I'm such a newbie and not sure if this applies to my case.

**The background:**

I'm using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/), and want to make a wrapper component that takes a react-query result object and a component, then shows spinner or the given component based on the query state (isLoading, isSuccess etc), whatever the query response data type is.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useQuery} from 'react-query'

interface WrapperProps {
   result: <type of react query result>;
   render: (data: <type of query data>) => React.ReactNode;
}

const Wrapper: React.FC<WrapperProps> = ({result, render}) => {
  if (result.isLoading) {
     return <div>spinner</div>
  }

  if (result.isSuccess) {
    return render(result.data)
  }

  return <div>otherwise</div>
}


const App: React.FC = () => { 
  const responseString = useQuery(
    ['string']
    async () => Promise.resolve("string")
  )

  const responseNumber = useQuery(
    ['number']
    async () => Promise.resolve(3)
  )

  return (
    <div>
    <Wrapper 
      result={responseString}
      render={(data) => (<div>successfully loaded string {data}</div>)} // <= want the data to be type string
    />
    <Wrapper 
      result={responseInt}
      render={(data) => (<div>successfully loaded int {data}</div>)} // <= want the data to be type number
    />
    </div>

  )
}
```

*1 the type of `useQuery` is something like [this](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/7aadd6896dd8a36e3f4ff8e7153a080528807d03/src/react/useQuery.ts#L29-L41)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You need to update `Wrapper` component a bit.

First of all, you need to get rid `FC`. Instead you need to add extra generic type to infer query result.

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from 'react-query'

interface WrapperProps<T> {
  result: UseQueryResult<T, unknown>
  render: (data: T) => JSX.Element;
}

const Wrapper = <T,>({ result, render }: WrapperProps<T>) => {
  if (result.isLoading) {
    return <div>spinner</div>
  }

  if (result.isSuccess) {
    return render(result.data)
  }

  return <div>otherwise</div>
}


const App: React.FC = () => {
  const responseString = useQuery(
    ['string'],
    async () => Promise.resolve("string")
  )

  const responseNumber = useQuery(
    ['number'],
    async () => Promise.resolve(3)
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper
        result={responseString}
        render={(data /** string */) => (<div>successfully loaded string {data}</div>)}
      />
      <Wrapper
        result={responseNumber}
        render={(data /** number */) => (<div>successfully loaded int {data}</div>)}
      />
    </div>

  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTRJY4BvOAVwGckBFepKATwBo4BVZmw6dkjegBt4AXzjZcBIuhgBaAI7suZCgDsYHTOiRwA6lBRgwHAAo4wjADwAVAHy1ScOETGSAXP0EaIkjeME689NoA1toQAO7azu6eSNoAJhx%20ABSpKDAofo4AlHAAvK4AUgDKABoAdACi4kggKTAA3KRS5GgQ2ozwpuaWUKVwYc6ZdF4SMLxEaRxwUn6DFta2Di7FZW4ewJhwmdOStcCMADIQKKnA2gDmxTRJHkQw9FDaYzcAbs6MYLdtBx7AB6H6JDxdJL7Q7HGCnRiVehoNDBRiPZ7JN4fZILKBHYIzWo5PKFJJQl5IbGfezgiAwAAWHFiZyQoPBnXIpB6fXgAEELH5kEpagAxADCo0y21cTw8PP6yX%20vWYlRgUFud1GTFYgUymIA2vh%20hr7vgALrcTEoRicbRoQ4yuA2XCs2peCDib5ITIAIhNmt9ZI8ZKSCvgXkgfSQADl6CAAEaLEoMALCfUeDxG7TxpNQC1WzNwG12h3S0quF0gN0er0%20gDMwbgocp1MOmNpwF%20mI89lWwx7mbhJRokZVSDVpruXSLRfm6SgI%20yuRQcBBACp13AA-c4OuQU7Mp3fmIUWjMBJxJw4OIrulUtv1ZraCSUFJ2V3nIUZ7OQRDZ32ZhrFAg6UiEI5jtGcaJhwP6zriC5Lq%20a6bnAOYwSM%206HsefzIqijCMBe4hXjed5IA%20tzwDQr7vmCn7foOf4dnR3ZJGSUhAA)

Please keep in mind that it is impossible to infer component props with extra generic and `FC` explicit type.

Please be aware that TS since [2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements) supports explicit generics for react  components