# Is there a way to extract generic type parameters from a type using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Typescript comes with a few nice type arithmetic operations like this one:

```
let target: ReturnType<typeof AcceptTerms>;
```

In this example `AcceptTerms` is a function that returns `Operation<AcceptTermsParams, string>`.

I'm wondering if it is possible to extract the generic type parameters and apply them to another type of a similar shape.

What I'm trying to achieve in practice is to generate a `Permission` object for all my `Operation`s:

```
type Permission<I, O> {
    name: string;
    operationName: string;
    // ...
}

type Operation<I, O> = {
    name: string;
    // ...
};
```

My problem is that I don't have instances of `Operation`s that I can use, only functions that return `Operation`s (hence the `ReturnType<typeof AcceptTerms>`).

Right now this is how I create permissions for an `Operation`:

```
const allowViewAvailableBasketsForAll: Permission<void, Basket[]> = {
    name: "Allow view available baskets for all",
    operationName: VIEW_AVAILABLE_BASKETS_NAME,
    policies: [allowAllPolicy()],
};
```

But it would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
export const withAllowAllFor = <??extract type params of operation somehow??>(name: string): Permission<I, O> => ({
    name: `Allow ${name} for all`,
    operationName: name,
    policies: [allowAllPolicy()],
});
```

So instead of supplying `I` and `O` by hand:

```
<I, O, T extends Operation<I, O>>
```

Can I somehow derive them from a type of `Operation<I, O>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: how to extract the generic parameter from a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851268/typescript-how-to-extract-the-generic-parameter-from-a-type)

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort". The duplicate is literally the first link for the "extract generic type parameter typescript" search on Google.

Comment: > The duplicate is literally the first link for the "extract generic type parameter typescript" search on Google

For me it is not, and I wasn't able to find that answer.

Comment: So, is that link an answer?

Comment: No, as it only handles single type parameters.