Enforcing strict field validation in Mongoose queries with TypeScript
Is it possible to make TypeScript don't compile when writing a Mongoose query that does not contain valid fields? For example, given the schema and the model below
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
})

const person = mongoose.model('PersonCollection', personSchema);

I want TypeScript to complain when I write this query since randomProperty does not exist on personSchema/ person.
person.find({ randomProperty: 123 })

I see that Mongoose allows querying on unknown properties since strictQuery is false by default in the migration guide to Mongoose 7. But I find it weirder that Mongoose don't complain when querying on unknown properties.
Additional context
I use automatic type interference by the way since that is recommended by Mongoose. And yes I have "strict": true in my tsconfig.
Versions

Mongoose 8.4.0
MongoDB 6.0
TypeScript 5.4.2


So I found a way by interfering types from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924506/9253300.
type TypeWithGeneric<T> = mongoose.Query<any, any, any, T, any, any>
type ExtractGeneric<Type> = Type extends TypeWithGeneric<infer X> ? X : never

const find = person.find
type ExtracedSchema = ExtractGeneric<ReturnType<typeof find>>

const findByQuery = async (query: Partial<ExtracedSchema>) => person.find(query)

const invalidResult = findByQuery({ name: "Donald", randomProperty: 123 }) // This will not compile
const result = findByQuery({ name: "Donald", age: 20 }) // This will compile


I found another solution by wrapping the model.
const safeModel = <T>(model: mongoose.Model<T>) => ({
  find: async (query: Partial<T>) => await model.find(query),
  updateMany: async (query: Partial<T>, data: Partial<T>) =>
    model.updateMany(query, data),
  create: async (data: Partial<T>) => await model.create(data)
})

const person = safeModel(personSchema)
person.find({ name: 'Donald' }) // This is now typed
person.find({ randomString: '30' }) // This will not compile


