# TypeScript conditional types: Extract component props type from react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, conditional-types

Using TypeScript 2.8 new conditional generic type feature, is it possible to extract the `TProps` of a `React.ComponentType<TProps>` component? I want a type that can **either** work on the `ComponentType` or the `TProps` itself, so you can - as a developer - pass either of both:

For example:

```
interface TestProps {
    foo: string;
}

const TestComponent extends React.Component<TestProps, {}> {
    render() { return null; }
}

// now I need to create a type using conditional types so that
// I can pass either the component or the props and always get the 
// TProps type back
type ExtractProps<TComponentOrTProps> = /* ?? how to do it? */

type a = ExtractProps<TestComponent> // type a should be TestProps
type b = ExtractProps<TestProps>     // type b should also be TestProps
```

Is this possible, and can anybody provide a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript React: Access component property types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230765/typescript-react-access-component-property-types)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There's a built-in helper for that

```
type AnyCompProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof AnyComp>
```

And it also works for native DOM elements:

```
type DivProps = React.ComponentProps<"div">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55005902/82609

Comment: Nice find Sebastien.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest to use `React.ComponentType`, because it will also include functional components:

```js
type ExtractProps<TComponentOrTProps> =
  TComponentOrTProps extends React.ComponentType<infer TProps>
    ? TProps
    : TComponentOrTProps;
```

Comment: Marking your answer as the right one now, as I also support functional/hooks based component introduced in React 16.8.

Comment: Why returning TComponentOrTProps if it doesn't extend from React.ComponentType ?

Answer (score 5):

It's a pretty straight forward application of conditional types and their inference behavior (using the `infer` keyword)

```
interface TestProps {
    foo: string;
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component<TestProps, {}> {
    render() { return null; }
}

type ExtractProps<TComponentOrTProps> = TComponentOrTProps extends React.Component<infer TProps, any> ? TProps : TComponentOrTProps;

type a = ExtractProps<TestComponent> // type a is TestProps
type b = ExtractProps<TestProps>     // type b is TestProps
```

Comment: This does not work anymore with React functional components introduced in React 16.8 (type React.FC<TProps>)

Comment: Why returning TComponentOrTProps if it doesn't extend from React.ComponentType ?

Comment: @CristianE. I think that this is needed to make `ExtractProps<TestProps>` work. If `ExtractProps` used with React.Component, it will extract props from it's declaration. Otherwise `ExtractProps` will assume that `TComponentOrTProps` is simply a `Props` interface and will return it as is