# How to extract nested type of an attribute passed as props to a React function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, react-typescript

If I have an interface defined for a function component, say

`MyFuncComp.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'

interface MyFuncCompProps {
    x: string
    y: number
    z: Array<ComplexType>
}

export function MyFuncComp(props: MyFuncCompProps) {
    return <>...</>
}
```

And I use the component in another component

`MyPage.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import {MyFuncComp} from 'MyFuncComp.tsx'

export function MyPage(){
    const [x, setX] = React.useState()
    const [y, setY] = React.useState()
    const [z, setZ] = React.useState()
    return <><MyFuncComp x={x} y={y} z={z} /></>
}
```

How can I extract the type of the attributes defined within the function component so that I may use the same type in `MyPage.tsx` as well?

I understand that I can export/import the interfaces all over, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I can infer the types from the functional component `MyFuncComp` in `MyPage.tsx`
This is how:

```
import {MyFuncComp} from 'MyFuncComp.tsx'
const InferredTypes = React.ComponentProps<typeof MyFuncComp>

export function MyPage(){
    const [x, setX] = React.useState<InferredTypes['x']>()
    const [y, setY] = React.useState<InferredTypes['y']>()
    const [z, setZ] = React.useState<InferredTypes['z']>()
    return <><MyFuncComp x={x} y={y} z={z} /></>
}
```

Referenced from answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075862/2717158) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220191/2717158)