# how to use the gluestack-ui types

Tags: react-native, native-base, gluestack

I am using the new components library called ([gluestack-ui](https://ui.gluestack.io)).

I am using typescript and I want to use the "Box" component props types interface in my component.

I can't find, is the interface exported?

```
import { Box } from '@gluestack-ui/themed'

export interface PaperProps extends PropsWithChildren  {}

export default function Paper({ children }: PaperProps) { 
  return <Box>{children}</Box>
}
```

In  material-ui for example, you can:

```
import { Box, type BoxProps } from '@mui/material'
```

the  I can for example:

```
export interface PaperProps extends PropsWithChildren & BoxProps  {}
```

How can I do the same with gluestack-ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, it's still in Beta, so there might be changes in the near future.

Even though I am uncertain if that's the intended usage, you could employ it in the following manner for now. Since `Box` is essentially `View` with additional styling and `Button` is `Pressable` with extra styling, you could utilize the native `react-native` *Prop Types* for these components.

There are a few more components like this, but unfortunately, I had to dig into the codebase since I couldn't find any [documentation](https://github.com/gluestack/gluestack-ui/blob/1cad9ea8f9ea727b7a55e91c2e44cd3d2a0307cb/packages/themed/src/components/Button/styled-components/Root.tsx#L521) on this yet.

```
import { ViewProps, PressableProps } from 'react-native'
import { Box, Button } from '@gluestack-ui/themed'

export interface MyFancyBoxProps extends PropsWithChildren<ViewProps>  {}

export default function MyFancyBox({ children }: MyFancyBoxProps) {
  return <Box>{children}</Box>
}

interface MyButtonProps extends PropsWithChildren<PressableProps> {}

function MyButton(props: MyButtonProps) {
  return <Button {...props} />
}
```

If it happens that there's no interface exported at all, you could always give `ComponentProps` a shot.

```
import { ComponentProps } from 'react'
import { Button, Box } from '@gluestack-ui/themed'


type ButtonProps = ComponentProps<typeof Button>;
type BoxProps = ComponentProps<typeof Box>;
```

[Matt Pocock has written a great article about it.](https://www.totaltypescript.com/react-component-props-type-helper) It's a great tool to have in your toolbox in general!

Comment: I used the `ComponentProps`, and read the article, now I'm feeling good :D

Comment: Awesome! I am glad it helped you out. The guy is known as the TypeScript Wizard for a reason haha

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ComponentProps` from react to do this.

```js
import { ComponentProps } from 'react'
import { Box } from '@gluestack-ui/themed'

export interface PaperProps extends ComponentProps<typeof Box>  {}

export default function Paper({ children }: PaperProps) { 
  return <Box>{children}</Box>
}
```

font : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220191/11705481