# Nested export in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, es6-modules

Lets say I want to make a library of icons for react+typescript.
As for example lets consider only 2 icons in this library: `Apple` and `Banana`.

I want to be able to import them separately as the following:

```js
import { Apple } from 'icons'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Apple/>
  }
}
```

Now lets consider a case when each icon has its **own** set of props:

```js
type Props = {}
class Apple extends React.Component<Props> {
}
```

```js
type Props = {}
class Banana extends React.Component<Props> {
}
```

Is there a way I can export these props **separately** through their components?
Like this:

```js
import { Apple } from 'icons'

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Apple.Props> {
  render() {
    // passing all the props into the apple
    return <Apple {...this.props}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could do something ugly with a `namespace Apple { type Props = {} }` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [answer to similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55005902/10246447).

Try

```js
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps<typeof Apple>> {
  render() {
    return <Apple {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

**Note that this assumes that the imported `Apple` is a valid react component.**

Also consider looking into this [typescript cheatsheet for react](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react) to have a good grasp of what typescript can do for react.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to exporting the component, you can export the type as well.

```
export type AppleProps = {}
export class Apple extends React.Component<AppleProps> {
}
```

You can then use them as:

```
import { Apple, AppleProps } from 'icons'
```

Comment: Does it means that I can't access exported props using `Apple.Props` and forced to make aliases in the root file for all the icons?

Comment: `Apple.Props` does not exist. Unless you explicitly set it, the ideal approach to access the props would be `ComponentProps<typeof Apple>` as @98sean98 suggested.