# TypeScript get Props Type from Component and Omit properties from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm working on a TypeScript function for a React "Higher Order Component." It takes:

- a component,
- a React Query `useQuery`-type function
- a function which returns an array of arguments to pass to the above `useQuery`-type function
- an optional `resultKey` which determines whether the result of the query should be spread into the component or nested under the given key.

Here's my implementation so far:

```
import React, { ComponentProps, FC } from "react";
import { UseQueryResult } from "react-query";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { ReactQueryLoader } from "Components/Shared/Elements/ReactQueryLoader";
import { useErrorToast } from "Utils/toasts";
import { useQueryParams } from "Utils/uris";

/** The useQuery function returning the query result */
type QueryFunc = (...args: unknown[]) => UseQueryResult;

/** Function returning array of args to pass to the query. Func is fed an object with URL params and passed component props. */
type GetArgsFunc<Props> = (getArgsArgs: {
  params: Record<string, string>;
  props: Props;
  queryParams: Record<string, unknown>;
}) => unknown[];

/** The string value to pass the result under to the child component. If undefined, result is spread */
type ResultKey = string | undefined;
type QueryTriplet<Props = Record<string, unknown>> = [QueryFunc, GetArgsFunc<Props>, ResultKey];
type QueryResult = Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, Record<string, unknown>>;

/**
 * Sort of the React Query version of React Redux's `connect`. This provides a neater interface for "wrapping" a component
 * with the API data it requires. Until that data resolves, a loading spinner is shown. If an error hits, a toast is shown.
 * Once it resolves, the data is passed to the underlying component.
 *
 * This "wrapper" is a bit more complex than the typical useQuery pattern, and is mostly better for cases where you want the "main" component
 * to receive the data unconditionally, so it can use it in a useEffect, etc.
 *
 * @param Component The Component to be rendered once the provided query has been resolved
 * @param useQuery The React Query hook to be resolved and passed to the Component
 * @param getArgs A function returning an ordered array of args to pass to the query func.
 *                     getArgs takes an object with URL `params` and passed `props`
 * @param resultKey The name of the prop to pass the query data to the Component as.
 *                  If not provided, the incoming data from the query will be spread into the Component's props.
 *
 * @example
 *
 * const OrgNameContent = ({ org }: { org: CompleteOrg }) => {
 *  const { name } = org;
 *  return <div>Org name: {name}</div>
 * }
 *
 * export const OrgName = withQuery(
 *  OrgNameContent,
 *  useGetOrg,
 *  ({ params }) => [params.uuid], // useGetOrg takes a single uuid param. The uuid comes from the URL.
 *  "org" // The OrgNameContent component expects an "org" prop, so we pass the data as that prop.
 * );
 */
export function withQuery<QueryFetchedKeys extends string = "", Props = Record<string, unknown>>(
  Component: FC<Props>,
  useQuery: QueryFunc,
  getArgs: GetArgsFunc<Props>,
  resultKey: ResultKey = undefined
) {
  type NeededProps = Omit<Props, QueryFetchedKeys>;
  const ComponentWithQuery: FC = (props: NeededProps) => {
    const showErrorToast = useErrorToast();
    const params = useParams();
    const queryParams = useQueryParams();
    const queryArgs = getArgs({ params, props, queryParams });
    const query = useQuery(...queryArgs) as UseQueryResult<QueryResult>;

    return (
      <ReactQueryLoader useQueryResult={query} handleError={showErrorToast}>
        {({ data }) => {
          const resultProps = (resultKey ? { [resultKey]: data } : data) as
            | QueryResult
            | Record<string, QueryResult> as Props;
          return <Component {...props} {...resultProps} />;
        }}
      </ReactQueryLoader>
    );
  };

  return ComponentWithQuery as FC<NeededProps>;
}
```

It works perfectly, but I'm having trouble getting the types right. Ideally, I would pass in a component (which is typed), and the function would "infer" from the component what the final set of props were that it needed from that component. Then, the result of calling `withQuery` on that component would return a component with a separate, smaller set of required props, because the `withQuery` call is providing props that DO NOT need to be passed in by the parent component.

For example, if I did this:

```
type SomeComponentProps = { uuid: string, org: Org };
const SomeComponentBase: FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({ org }) => (
  <span>{org.name}</span>
)

// Would expect `uuid` as a prop, but not `org`
export const SomeComponent = withQuery(
  SomeComponent,
  useGetOrg, // This query expects a uuid arg, and returns an org
  ({ props }) => [props.uuid], // Grab the passed uuid, and pass it in as the first and only arg to the useOrg function
  'org' // Assert that the result of the query (an org), should be passed as a prop under the key "org"
)
```

The `withQuery` function would ideally be "smart" enough to:

1. Infer the "full" prop types (org and uuid) from the component it is passed
2. Understand that because "org" is the `resultKey`, that prop is being passed in from the query, and does not need to be passed in from outside. Thus, it can be `Omit`ted from the exported component type.

Super, super ideally, if `useGetOrg` was typed, and no resultKey was passed (meaning the results of the query were spread as props), the `withQuery` function would be able to detect that ALL the keys of that response are provided by the query, and consequently would not need to be passed in by the rendering parent component.

Is this possible? It's a bit beyond my TypeScript capacities at present.

Can you help me rewrite this in a way that handles this type inference such that the parent component only needs to pass in the props that `withQuery` doesn't itself provide?

Or, if this isn't possible, maybe when you call `withQuery`, you can pass in the type of the props of the produced component?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from your question, you want to infer the type of component passed into `withQuery` and remove from its props, the property passed into `resultKey` argument.

You can use the `React.ComponentProps` utility type to extract the component's props type. Then you can use `Omit` type utility to extract the property passed into the `resultKey` argument from the props of the component.

```
type ComponentProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Component>
type NeededProps = Omit<ComponentProps, typeof resultKey>
```

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55005902/12182979) to learn more about extracting a React Component's Prop type from the component itself.

Alternatively, if you want to infer the result type of Query and remove properties from props based on that result type, you can do it using `ResultType` utility type and `keyof` function:

```
type KeysOfDataReturnType = keyof ReturnType<typeof useQuery>['data'];
type NeededProps = Omit<Props, KeysOfDataReturnType>;
```